# Create view for Owner Team and it's Team members Cases in CRM 2013

Tags: view, case, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to create a System View that not only shows me the a specific Team's cases but also shows me that Team's members cases.

I am able to setup the view to show the Team's cases or the Team's Members cases separately, but I cannot combine the two into the a single view.

I appreciate anyone's insight on this.

Comment: Advanced Find can't do it, you'll have to build a Report

Answer (score 0):

is that an option for you hardcode the users that are present in a team? In that case you can put the owner as an OR specify the team, and the users. Otherwise you will need to go with Alex option.